# Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value. although i am returning snapshot.val();

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a cloud function for my project . its being last 12 hours that i am stuck with this error "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value"
i have tried alot to remove it but not able to find how to solve it

```
exports.Notify = functions.database.ref('blood_share/Notifications/{user}/{notificationid}').onWrite((change, context) => {

        const username=context.params.user;
        const notifyid=context.params.notificationid;


        const query = admin.database().ref("blood_share/Notifications").child(username).child(notifyid);
        query.once('value').then(snapshot=>{
         const event = snapshot.val();

        const notificationMessage = event.messsage;
        const token_id=event.reciever_appid;
        console.log("message"+notificationMessage);



        //create notification Json

        const payLoad = {
       notification:{
         title: "New Request For Food",
         body: "kuch b",
         icon: "default"
       }
     };

      return snapshot.val();

         }).catch(error => {
         console.error(error);

         });    

   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the value when the `query.once('value')` promises resolves.

To clarify this, look at this:

```
let a = 0;
asyncFunctionPromise.then(() => {
 a = 1;
});
console.log(a); // Will print 0 instead of
```

Instead directly return the promise `return query.once('value').then(....` or build your own with

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  query.once('value').then(snapshot=>{
       // do something
       resolve(snapshot.val()); // To resolve the promise with snapshot.val()
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to return the promise

```
 return query.once('value').then(snapshot=>{
  //....
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of return snapshot.val() which is a value, return a Promise

```
return Promise.resolve(snapshot.val());
```